# Log Files - difference between using sudo or not

Tags: command-line, log

You start by going into the logs with cd /var/log

Then you want to look at the kern.log

I did this firstly by using sudo less kern.log, then less kern.log

Both outputs were the same.

So what exactly is the difference between using sudo for the command, or leaving it without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sudo` lets you access whether it be to read (as in your case) or to write to folders and files irrespective of the ownership status or permission status of those folders or files.

In this case of the `/var/log` folder these files usually don't need you to be the `root user` to read from them hence log files are accessible for most users at least the read part. But we have certain processes that will produce log entries that only the `system user` (that created those log) or the `root user` can read from such files, examples include `auth.log`, `mail.log`, `php7.2-fpm.log` etc. These I have picked from my own `/var/log` folder.

Run the command `ls -l /var/log` to see those files and the permissions that are associated with them, including their ownerships. From there you can decern when you will need to use `sudo` and when you will not.

Answer (score 2):

For succesful use of the `less`-command you will need read-permissions. Let's check the permissions of the file:

```
~$ ll /var/log/kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1366232 Jan  3 19:50 /var/log/kern.log
```

The file is owned by the user `syslog` who has read and write permissions. The file is also associated with the group `adm` which has read permission. As you were able to read the file as a regular (non-root) user, you are obviously a member of the `adm`-group. You may check it with the `groups`-command.

```
~$ groups
mook adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` command allows you run commands with security privileges of another user, by default as the `superuser` or `root user`. you can not run the `init` command as normal user until you use `sudo`, like that there are lots of other administrative commands and operation where you must use `sudo` to perform those operations, there are lot of security reason why we are using `sudo`.